# Comparing two consecutive rows and creating a new column based on a specific logical operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns

```
df = ['xPos', 'lineNum']   
import pandas as pd



data = '''\
   xPos lineNum
    40  1
    50  1
    75  1
    90  1
    42  2
    75  2
    110 2
    45  3
    70  3
    95  3
    125 3
    38  4
    56  4
    74  4'''
```

I have created the aggregate data frame for this by using

`aggrDF = df.describe(include='all')`

command

and I am interested in the minimum of the xPos value. So, i get it by using

```
minxPos = aggrDF.ix['min']['xPos']
```

**Desired output**

```
data = '''\
xPos lineNum xDiff
40  1   2
50  1   10
75  1   25
90  1   15
42  2   4
75  2   33
110 2   35
45  3   7
70  3   25
95  3   25
125 3   30
38  4   0
56  4   18
74  4   18'''
```

**The logic**
I want to compere the two consecutive rows of the data frame and calculate a new column based on this logic:

```
 if( df['LineNum'] != df['LineNum'].shift(1) ):
    df['xDiff'] = df['xPos'] - minxPos
  else:
    df['xDiff'] = df['xPos'].shift(1)
```

Essentially, I want the new column to have the difference of the two consecutive rows in the df, as long as the line number is the same.

If the line number changes, then, the xDiff column should have the difference with the minimum xPos value that I have from the aggregate data frame.

Can you please help? thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `groupby` lineNum and `apply` the condition you already writing down

```
df['xDiff']=np.concatenate(df.groupby('lineNum').apply(lambda x : np.where(x['lineNum'] != x['lineNum'].shift(1),x['xPos'] - x['xPos'].min(),x['xPos'].shift(1)).astype(int)).values)
df
Out[76]: 
    xPos  lineNum  xDiff
0     40        1      0
1     50        1     40
2     75        1     50
3     90        1     75
4     42        2      0
5     75        2     42
6    110        2     75
7     45        3      0
8     70        3     45
9     95        3     70
10   125        3     95
11    38        4      0
12    56        4     38
13    74        4     56
```

Comment: Check your output, it's not exactly what the OP wanted (unless I missed something)

Comment: @sacul this is my understand ...base on his wording *If the line number changes, then, the xDiff column should have the difference with the minimum xPos value that I have from the aggregate data frame.*

Comment: From their desired output I think they mean the diff between the value of xpos and their minxPos variable when the line number changes

Comment: @sacul if that is the expected out put , I think op already get it right ? even his answer looks no neat , but consider the speed should be faster than apply

Comment: True, I just thought the op was looking for alternate non-loopy ways to get their “desired output” df. It’s a bit unclear...

Answer (score 2):

These two lines should do it:

```
df['xDiff'] = df.groupby('lineNum').diff()['xPos']

df.loc[df['xDiff'].isnull(), 'xDiff'] = df['xPos'] - minxPos

>>> df
    xPos  lineNum  xDiff
0     40        1    2.0
1     50        1   10.0
2     75        1   25.0
3     90        1   15.0
4     42        2    4.0
5     75        2   33.0
6    110        2   35.0
7     45        3    7.0
8     70        3   25.0
9     95        3   25.0
10   125        3   30.0
11    38        4    0.0
12    56        4   18.0
13    74        4   18.0
```

Comment: Thank you Sacul for your prompt response. I appreciate it!. I will try this as soon as I get to office, and will accept the answer once I try the solution.

Comment: when I tired this, I am getting this error  df['LWS'] = df.groupby('LineNum').diff()
        #df.loc[df['LWS'].isnull(), 'LWS'] = df['x0'] - df['x0'].min()     ERROR IS Wrong number of items passed 19, placement implies 1

Comment: You probably have columns that you aren't showing in your original post. Try using `df.groupby('lineNum').diff()['xPos']`